# Django-Channels - /admin/ portal not displaying new models created

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-channels

I have a implemented django-channels. Earlier I was using Apache to serve the django application, but now Channels uses Daphne(server) to serve my application. After adding two new models to the models.py file, I migrated the changes to database. I also registered the models in the admin.py file.

Even so, the models are not showing up in the Django-admin panel. 
I tried the following:

- Stopped Daphne process.
- Started Apache server. The Admin panel started showing the new models.
- Stopped Apache server. Started Daphne on port80. This time Admin panel did not show the new models.

I am wondering what might be the case. As far as I can guess, whenever the application is served by Apache, updated files are used. Whereas, whenever the application is served by Django-Channels (Daphne), the old configurations (without the new models) are used.

**Would like all the help to solve this issue. How can I make Django-Channels(Daphne) reflect the changes, the new models in my Django Admin console.**

Comment: Did you restart your worker processes? Those are the processes that use your actual code, Daphne only uses your channel routing configuration.

Comment: Hey! Restarting the working processes made it work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by knbk, restarting the worker processes made it reflect the changes on my Admin portal. That was the only thing I hadn't tried.